# Access polymer component properties from callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, polymer

With this polymer element definition:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'hello-world',
        properties: {
            dataId: {
                type: String
            },
            value: {
                type: String
            }
        },
        ready: function() {
            console.log(this.dataId);
            registerCallback(this.dataId, function (data) {
                var z = data.someValue;
                this.value = z;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

When it tries to set `this.value`, `this` is actually the data, not the element.  I want it to set the polymer property "value" to the value of z.  How can I do this?

Here is the `registerCallback()` if needed:

```
function registerCallback(id, callback) {
    callbackMap[id] = callback;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it

- As you already know `this` has a different meaning inside the `callback` so one way would be to store `this`(Polymer element) inside some other variable

  ```
  var self=this;
  registerCallback(function(){
     self.data = some value
  })
  ```
- Second option is to `bind` `this` with your callback

  ```
  registerCallback(function(){
     this.data= some value
  }.bind(this));
  ```